# Java: Extracting Instagram likes?

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, extract, instagram

So it's a pretty straightforward question, I was just wondering, does anyone know how I would be able to do this, preferably using purely java/at least code that can be executed from a Java program?

Currently I am using the following method in which the webpage is downloaded from the server:

```
        URL url = new URL(u);
        URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
        uc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");
        InputStream inputStream = uc.getInputStream();

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("currentImagePage.html");

        int bytesRead = -1;
        int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
```

And the resulting HTML document returned can be seen here:
http://pastebin.com/262h22PQ

If you look at line 110, that's the only real thing I can see of any interest:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window._strings = {
  //other random crap
  "%(count)s people liked this photo": "%(count)s people liked this photo",
```

But is there anyway I would be able to access the count variable? If there is, I'd appreciate anyone who could point me on the right track

---

I have actually got a method that is working, however that involves loading the webpage using selenium's webdriver and then calling the .getPageSource() method. This will then return the following page source:

http://pastebin.com/ZZtNiWPw

As Instagram says "[user x], [user y], [user z] & [number of others] liked this", you can then extract that from the string and get the following line:

```
<span data-reactid=".0.0.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.1.0.0.0:1.$tx7:0" class="llRemainingCount">3,511</span>
```

There's one problem with this method though...having to load in potentially thousands of image pages just to extract the number of likes is VERY slow.

---

So I guess really what I'm asking is 1) can I get the first method to return the same page source as method two or 2) is there anyway I can access the %(count) variables in method 1? Or if anyone has a better solution, I'd be really grateful :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You are going the complicated way.

Most big websites provide you with a pretty good API that can be called from Java.
Some even delivery libraries dedicated to those APIs

Instagram API: http://instagram.com/developer/

Instagram doesnt deliver Java libraries tho. But Java does deliver an API for RESTful Web Services called JAX-RS. Im not an expert on this but with some googling you might find more

---

EDIT: added more Info about authentication need for retrieving "likes"

Excerpt from http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/

> **Do you need to authenticate?**
>
> For the most part, Instagram’s API only requires the use of a client_id. A client_id simply associates your server, script, or program with a specific application. However, some requests require authentication - specifically requests made on behalf of a user.

TL;DR no you dont have to authenticate for access to likes on public media...
It isnt very well documented on the site tho...
I just tested in the [console](http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/) to see what i get back.

On "users/self/media/liked" i got:
`"error_message": "Missing access_token URL parameter."`

But on "media/{mediaid}/likes" i got this:
`"error_message": "Missing client_id or access_token URL parameter."`

Some reading and fiddling around always solves the problems :P

Comment: I did look at the API, but from what I could make of it, I've got a feeling you had to be logged in to do a lot of it. Maybe I'm wrong, but if you do have to log in, that's just an unnacessary hassle that most users aren't going to want to do...

Comment: dont know if it notifies you if i edit my post, but i needed the formatting ^^

Comment: @SteveM you don't need to be logged in to access anything that is publicly available